# Spectral Radiance unit Flicks is not correct

Tags: bugs, units

**Bug introduced in version 10.3 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.**

---

I was pleasantly surprised that Mathematica (10.3, 10.4, 10.4.1, 11.0 and 11.0.1) had the unit $\text{flick}$  until I spent several hours trying to figure out why all my calculations were million times off! I think this is a very simple bug. That unless you are dealing with odd spectral radiance units you would never see it.

Mathematica's internal definition for a $\text{flick}$ is wrong.

A $\text{flick}$ is:
$1 \text{flick} = 1\; \frac{\text{W}}{\text{cm}^2\; \text{sr}\; \mu \text{m}}$
Here are some external links for the definition of a $\text{flick}$
[Wikipedia (Flick)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flick_(physics))
[A Dictionary of Units of Measurement](https://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/dictF.html)
[Physics Wiki](http://research.omicsgroup.org/index.php/Flick_(physics))

Set L to be one $\text{flick}$

```
 L = Quantity[1, "Flicks"]

 (*
   1flicks 
 *)
```

Lets convert one $\text{flick}$ to one  $\frac{\text{W}}{\text{cm}^2\; \text{sr}\; \mu \text{m}}$

```
  UnitConvert[L, "Watts"/(("Centimeters")^2 "Steradians"  "Micrometers")]
 (*
 1 000 000 W/(cm^2 \[Micro]m sr)
 *)
```

Have I missed something simple in how I'm doing the conversion? I'm going to guess that because the $\mu\text{flick}$ is the most common unit of $\text{flick}$ that a $\mu\text{flick}$ accidentally got defined as a $\text{flick}$.

Comment: As a matter of policy, we traditionally do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been verified by others. Nevertheless, running `UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Flicks"]] // N` does show that something's off, so this is certainly a bug, and I'll let you off this time.

Comment: Sorry I did quick look over the Mathematica meta but must have missed that.

Comment: It's [in meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/354) (there are also a number of related questions), and it is also in the [tag wiki](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs)

Comment: Yep there it is, Sorry. It is my intent to follow the rules.

Comment: `L = Quantity[1, "Microflicks"]` confirms your hypothesis !

Comment: @c186282 You should report this to Wolfram Support, if you haven't yet! As you probably know, this forum is not associated with Wolfram, so reporting bugs here does not notify Wolfram.

Comment: Yes I have sent a link to this post to my Wolfram contact.

Comment: As I said "Yes I have sent a link to this post to my Wolfram contact." well Flicks are still wrong in 11.0

Comment: Just got 11.0.1 and still wrong!

Comment: The page for F on [A dictionary of units of measurements](https://www.unc.edu/~rowlett/units/dictF.html) is 404 by now!